# Solve $2\tau(n^2)=3\tau(n)$ in the set of naturals

Tags: number-theory

$\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

My idea was that I need to approximate the growth of $\tau$ and then find $n_0$ after which all $\tau(n^2)$ are greater than $\frac{3}{2}\tau(n)$. I assume that the $n_0$ wouldn't be that large since $\tau(n^2)$ seems to be much bigger than $\tau(n)$. Then I'd just check for all $n\in\{1,...,n_0\}$

So, how do I do it?

Comment: Do you know a formula for $\tau(n)$in terms of the prime factorisation of $n$?

Comment: I think the solutions are only prime numbers.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sure but that didn't really help me much.

Comment: Number of divisors of $n$ including or excluding $1$ and/or $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's $n=p_1^{\alpha _1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha _k}$, thus $n^2=p_1^{2\alpha _1}\cdots p_k^{2\alpha _k}$, so 
$$
2(2\alpha _1 +1)\cdots(2\alpha _k+1)=2\tau(n^2)=3\tau(n)=3(\alpha _1 +1)\cdots(\alpha _k+1)
$$
It's easy to see that $n$ must be prime.

Comment: What what I got as well. It's just not that easy to see for me. How do you justify that formally?

Comment: $\frac{2\alpha + 1}{\alpha + 1}\ge \frac{3}{2}$ if $\alpha \ge1$

Comment: Yeah, but how do you know you can just compare the same-indexed factors like that?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand your question.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm just overcomplicating it. I can see why this works.